# Angular 2 + Cordova: ChangeDetection inside Cordova function

Tags: javascript, cordova, angular

I've got the following problem. In my application I've a so called download.component and a download.service. In the download component I have some visual indicators to display the current progress of the download. In the download.service I'm accessing the functionality of the cordova-file-transfer-plugin.

The component and the service basically communicate with an Observable, which will inform the component if there is any progress during the download process. The service has a download-method which returns a Promise. Which resolves with true after the file has been downloaded.

My problem is that, the attributes (which feed the visual indicator) are not updated on the component. The file-transfer-plugin offers an onprogress-callback, here the next-function is called to update the subscribers (the download-component).

To be even more precise the attribute itself seems to be updated. I see it when a log it to the console. But the template is not updated. So I also tried to use methods like appRef.tick or cdRef.detectChanges. Here are the relevant code parts. I really don't know what is causing this issue.

download.service

```
    public download(item: any) {
    let self = this;

    return new Promise((resolve) => {

    window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, function onFileSystemSuccess(fileSystem) {

        fileSystem.root.getFile(item.item_id + '.zip', { create: true, exclusive: false }, function gotFileEntry(fileEntry) {
        let fileTransfer = new FileTransfer();

        fileTransfer.onprogress = (progressEvent) => {
            self._downloadProgress.next(progressEvent.loaded / progressEvent.total);
        };

        let path = environment.cordovaPath;

        fileTransfer.download(item.url, path + item.item_id + '.zip',
            function (theFile) {
            console.log('download done');
                resolve(true);
            },
            function (error) {
            resolve(false);
            }
        );
        }, function (evt) {
        resolve(false);
        });
    },
        function (evt) {
        resolve(false);
        });
    });

}
```

download.component

```
this.subProgess = this.downloadService.download.subscribe((value) => {
  this.dynamic = Math.round(value * 100);
  console.log(this.dynamic); // actually logs the right value
  if (value > 0) {
  // triggering the change detection manually 
    this.appRef.tick();
    this.cdRef.detectChanges();
  }
});
```

I also tried to pass this.dynamic as parameter to the download-method and updating it there like this:

```
this.zone.run(() => dynamic = progressEvent.loaded / progressEvent.total);
```

Also no success. Does anybody has an advice how to solve this problem?

Comment: Have you found a solution to this? I have a similar issue with a splitter element. I'm counting the width of an element by the drag events of the splitter and pushing the correct with to the element with [style.width.%]="width$ | async" I realized, that the changes will appear on the DOM but much slower than in a simple browser, it's like the change detection itself is slower on cordova, but only if you bind to the DOM. If I change this to manipulate the width of the element directly element.nativeElement.style.width = ..., then the change will appear instantly. And I don't really get, why...

Comment: @IThomas91 no unfortunatley not :(

Comment: Well, I asked for help in my case here in StackOverflow, but I did not found a solution yet :( If I find it, I will share it here as well.

Comment: A little late, but I share my experiences. I tried everything I could find or heard, even tried to get hints from other colleagues, but the only thing that worked if I called the `detectChanges()` manually whnever I changed the value. The interesting thing is, that it is only needed in cordova, it works just fine without it in any browsers.